# When Exactly does Django Run the Query?

Tags: python, django

While I understand the high-level ideas of Django's QuerySet and lazy execution, I don't see in Django (3.1.2) source code how query execution is triggered (i.e., database is being hit). For example, according to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get), `get()` query seems to hit the database immediately. But looking at the source code (`django.db.models.query`):

```
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Perform the query and return a single object matching the given
        keyword arguments.
        """
        clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.query.can_filter() and not self.query.distinct_fields:
            clone = clone.order_by()
        limit = None
        if not clone.query.select_for_update or connections[clone.db].features.supports_select_for_update_with_limit:
            limit = MAX_GET_RESULTS
            clone.query.set_limits(high=limit)
        num = len(clone)
        if num == 1:
            return clone._result_cache[0]
        if not num:
            raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
                "%s matching query does not exist." %
                self.model._meta.object_name
            )
        raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
            'get() returned more than one %s -- it returned %s!' % (
                self.model._meta.object_name,
                num if not limit or num < limit else 'more than %s' % (limit - 1),
            )
        )
```

I don't see where `clone` (which is a `QuerySet` object) sends to the database engine its `query` (i.e., `self._query` that contains the actual `Query` object being parsed into SQL) and somehow caches the result in the `_result_cache`. In fact, when I tried to step through the code, at some point, `self._result_cache` "magically" got populated with query results. I never stepped into any SQL-related code, like `results_iter()` or `execute_sql()` in `django.db.models.sql.compiler`, which I assume must be called to interact with the database backend? My guess is that Django is running a different process/thread and PyCharm only steps through the main thread? If this is the case, can someone point out some relevant code? I can't seem to find any help from Google myself. Thanks!

EDIT:
I know from looking at the code that `_fetch_all()` can trigger database hits because it connects to `ModelIterable`, which executes SQL commands and processes the results into Python objects, but how come I never stepped into this method ever? I guess the better question for this is, when is `_fetch_all()` ever called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you have added, see this line:

```
num = len(clone)
```

One can see that we are calling `len` on a queryset. According to [When QuerySets are evaluated - Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated):

> **len()**. A **QuerySet** is evaluated when you call **len()** on it. This, as you might expect, returns the length of the result list.

Looking further in the [source code - GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f5a22442176878d07e80ae5ba0af1dd8d6910fbd/django/db/models/query.py#L261-L263) `len` would call `_fetch_all()` as you had correctly assumed is where the results are coming from:

> ```
> def __len__(self):
>     self._fetch_all()
>     return len(self._result_cache)
> ```

The above referred documentation also notes when exactly a queryset is evaluated.