# How Does Django Manager Orchestrate QuerySet?

Tags: python, django

This is a follow-up question from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66792326/when-exactly-does-django-run-the-query). For the sake of completeness and self-containment, I will include all necessary bits in this question.

Consider a very simple example:

```
# Models
class Cart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# Execution
class Test(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Save a new cart
        c = Cart(name="MyCart")
        c.save()
        # Save two items to the cart
        t = Item(name="item1", cart=c)
        t.save()
        Item.objects.create(name="item2", cart=c)

    def simpleTest(self):
        i = Item.objects.get(id=2) # <--- breakpoint
        # Do something, but not important for this question
```

I am using PyCharm to try to understand the inner workings of Django. If we put a breakpoint at the marked line and step into the method call `get()`. After we get a Manager from `__get__` in `ManagerDescriptor` (due to `.objects`), the execution now goes to this class method in `BaseManager`:

```
@classmethod
    def _get_queryset_methods(cls, queryset_class):
        def create_method(name, method):
            def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) # <--- Starts here
            manager_method.__name__ = method.__name__
            manager_method.__doc__ = method.__doc__
            return manager_method
```

The execution stops at the marked line above. If we step into it, `get_queryset()` is first called, which returns a new `QuerySet` object,  as expected. Note that the new `QuerySet` object initializes `self._result_cache` to `None`. This attribute caches the result of the `QuerySet`. After the object is initialized, the `get()` method is finally called. **However, if we inspect the calling `QuerySet` object (which is the object that is just initialized), its `_result_cache` has already been populated with the two `Item` objects that I have saved.** I suspect something is probably happening in a different thread, perhaps? Can someone experienced in Django point out the relevant code that is executed between the end of `get_queryset()` and before the beginning of `get()`? I can't seem to find any documentation myself.

Thanks!

Comment: `getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)` here `name` contains `get` (You have called the `get` method). Hence by writing `getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)` you are calling the `get` method, so the `_result_cache` being populated is correct. There is no other thread coming in the picture here.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat What I don't understand is *at what point* the `_result_cache` is being populated? At the entrance of the `get` method, it is already filled with objects. Why? (The `self.get_queryset()` method has just set the `_result_cache` to `None` right before `get()` is called)

Comment: `getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)` gets the `get` method then writing `getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)` calls the get method. The `_result_cache` is set **after** the `get` method is called. Why don't you simply **step into** the function while debugging (as you are using a debugger) if you don't understand where the result is coming from.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I did actually step into the `get()` method and like I said, the `_result_cache` is already populated the moment I stepped into the `get()` method, so either I misunderstood your response or what you said is simply not true.